# Plotting/drawing arrays from a specific date

Tags: pine-script

Thanks to mr_statler I managed to plot the arrays using

`safePlotD1 = array.size(D1) > 0 ? array.get(D1, 0) : na`

However I would need to offset the plot to the current date without using `plot offset=`, so it starts where the `day = input.time` is as shown on the picture below, many thanks:
[image]

```
indicator("Volume avg", overlay = false)

day = input.time(timestamp("14 Feb 2023 00:00"), "Date", confirm= false)

w1back = time >= day - 604800000 and  time < day - 604800000 + 86400000


var D1 =  array.new_float(0)
if w1back
    array.unshift(D1, volume)

var my_array = array.new_float(0)

safePlotD1 = array.size(D1) > 0 ? array.get(D1, 0) : na

plot(safePlotD1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that at most of the bars, the array size will be 0, you can check the array size before plotting:

```
safePlotD1 = array.size(D1) > 0 ? array.get(D1, 0) : na
safePlotD2 = array.size(D2) > 0 ? array.get(D2, 0) : na
safePlotD3 = array.size(D3) > 0 ? array.get(D3, 0) : na
safePlotD4 = array.size(D4) > 0 ? array.get(D4, 0) : na

plot(safePlotD1)
plot(safePlotD2)
plot(safePlotD3)
plot(safePlotD4)
```

You can also average the results from those variables. Since some of the variables will be `na`, I think the easiest way to go is creating a new array and average that array:

```
avgArray = array.from(safePlotD1, safePlotD2, safePlotD3, safePlotD4)
avg = array.avg(avgArray)
plot(avg)
```

Comment: Thank you mr_statler, plot now works! However it's keeping the values where they have been collected into the arrays, would there be a way to shift them over to the last current day?

Comment: If you want get the latest value from the array, you can either use the `array.unshift()` instead of `array.push()` and then get the first element using index 0, or you can leave the `array.push()` and get the last element of that array using `array.get(D1, array.size(D1) - 1)`. Your call